# AppBar icons in the Toolkit's DateTimePicker

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, datetimepicker, toolkit

I am building my application in the Windows Phone 8 framework. I am facing the critical problem here. Initially i developed my app using the Telerik's DateTime picker but unfortunately it had some animation and looping problem so i taken the DatePicker from the ToolKit and created the custom control with this. Unfortunately i am not able to access the AppBar of the DatePicker to update it based on my requirements. Is there any option to access the Application bar of the DatePicker in the Toolkit ?. Help can be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem and 
[this](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/workitem/7266) worked out great for me.